# Convert shell statement into OR

Tags: bash, shell

How would I do the following `OR` statement with the proper syntax:

```
if ps aux | (grep "[i]ngest_all.py" OR grep "[h]ello.py" ) > /dev/null
then
    echo "Script is already running. Skipping"
else
    exec "$DIR/ingest_all.py"
fi
```

Comment: Why do your file names have square brackets around the first character? Are there literally square brackets in the names or are you doing a regex character class?

Comment: It's a regex, so the `grep` itself doesn't return as one of the commands in `ps aux`.

Comment: Ahh, neat trick! If you are using OS X or have access to `pgrep` then the following might work well for you:  `pgrep -q aux ingest_all.py hello.py`. (`pgrep` ignores itself) and note that if you don't want output most of the greps (all?) will take a `-q` to be quite and avoid the redirect to `/dev/null`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an alternator (pipe character: |) to specify an OR inside of the grep regex.

For BSD grep, with basic regular expressions, (at least on OS X) use an escaped pipe: `\|`:

```
grep "[i]ngest_all.py\|[h]ello.py"
```

If you want you can also use extended regular expressions, where you don't need to escape the pipe character:

```
grep -E "[i]ngest_all.py|[h]ello.py"
```

or

```
egrep "[i]ngest_all.py|[h]ello.py"
```

Comment: Note that this will work with GNU `grep`, but according to POSIX you should use the `-E` option to enable extended regular expressions.  And that's not specifically a PCRE; it's just an ERE, Extended Regular Expression.

Comment: Does ubuntu use `GNU` or `POSIX`? What about Mac `OSX` ?

Comment: Ubuntu uses GNU `grep`; Mac OS X uses BSD `grep`.

Comment: @David542, POSIX is not a command, and neither is GNU; neither of them needs code highlighting.

Comment: In BSD grep on OS X the default is basic regular expressions (BREs), where to do alternation you use an escaped pipe. If you use extended regular expressions (EREs) then you don't use the escape, just a pipe.

Comment: `grep -E`, and no backslash escape, is definitely the safer approach from a portability perspective.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `awk`:

```
if ps aux | awk '/[i]ngest_all.py/||/[h]ello.py/{exit 0}END{exit 1}'
```